# Ellipsis is not showing up even if text overflows

Tags: css, text, overflow, ellipsis

App.js

```
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <p className="text">
        This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a
        test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is
        a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This
        is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a
        test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is
        a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This
        is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a
        test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is
        a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

style.css

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.text {
  padding: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 50px;
  background: yellow;
  height: 150px;
}
```

Also, please refer this sandbox link -> https://codesandbox.io/s/overflow-ellipsis-cx6d44

Currently, when the text overflows, it doesn't shows ellipsis in the end. See the below image.

[image: problem]

I want to have ellipsis at the end similar to this image.

[image: expected behavior]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add styles  display: -webkit-box;-webkit-box-orient: vertical;-webkit-line-clamp: 2;  to your existing code and remove styles from your existing code
padding: 20px;height: 150px;   no need of this style.

```css
.text{
display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
-webkit-line-clamp: 2;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
width: 200px;
margin: 50px;
background: yellow;
line-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
  <p class="text">
        This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a
        test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is
        a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This
        is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a
        test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is
        a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This
        is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a
        test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is
        a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!
    </p>
```

Comment: Thanks Sweta! It is now working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `white-space:nowrap` to your existing code should fix it for you.

Comment: But, it will constrain the text to only one line. I want the text to expand to the available space and add an ellipsis when it overflows.

Comment: In case of a multi-line truncation you could use `display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;(you can set this value according to your req)
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;`

Comment: Yeah, it partially solves the issue but, I'll need to truncate the text manually to fit the number of lines. Otherwise, it's adding the ellipsis and the rest of the test is followed below. I want it to automatically add an ellipsis when the text is about to overflow. Thanks for your response.